# How to prevent too many if-else conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, coding-style

I have controllers that control whether user can rent a product. I have many conditions to check, and each have different outcomes. I have too many `if` `else` statements. I wonder what design pattern I can follow to make it more readable.

```
if current_user
  if rental_valid?
    if current_user.approved
      if eligible_to_use?(product_id)
        # redirect_to payment
      else 
        # redirect_to :back
        # alert not eligible
      end 
    else
      # redirect_to verify_path
    end 
  else
    # redirect_to :back
    # alert, rental not valid
  end 
else
  # redirect_to login_path
end
```

Comment: looks like your 3 first `if` are generic enough to be moved to `before_action`

Comment: If possible, go for `case`.

Answer (score 5):

Supposing this is in a method:

```
return redirect_to login_path unless current_user
return redirect_to(:back; alert, rental not valid) unless rental_valid?
return redirect_to verify_path unless current_user.approved
return redirect_to(:back; alert not eligible) unless eligible_to_use?(product_id)
return redirect_to payment
```

Replace `return` with `break`, etc. if necessary to match the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has too many if-elses because it is trying to handle too many concerns (authentication, authorization, business logic). Refactoring the number of if-elses will reduce the lines of code, but won't improve maintainability in the long run. Try to understand and manage the individual concerns separately.

The `current_user` check can be delegated to an authentication `before_action` in `ApplicationController.

`current_user.approved` looks like an authorization concern and should be handled by your authorization solution, perhaps `cancancan` or `pundit`. (at the simplest, an authorization `before_action` in this controller)

After those two are taken care of, the remainder can be handled with a [Policy Object](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) to encapsulate domain specific logic. This would make your controller action look similar the following:

```
policy = ProductRentalPolicy.new(current_user, product) 
if policy.eligible_to_use? && policy.rental_valid?
  redirect_to payment_path
else
  redirect_to :back, error: policy.error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to move common and reuseable redirects into methods.

```
before_action :user_authorizied, only: [:method_name]
before_action :rental_validability, only: [:method_name]
before_action :user_approved, only: [:method_name]

def method_name
  #...
  if eligible_to_use?(product_id)
    # redirect_to payment
  else 
    # redirect_to :back
    # alert not eligible
  end
end

private

def user_authorizied
  redirect_to(login_path) unless current_user
end

def rental_validability
  redirect_to(:back) unless rental_valid?
end

def user_approved
  redirect_to(verify_path) unless current_user.approved
end
```